# How to add an element in a Struct

Tags: go, struct

I have this Struct in Golang:

```
type User struct {
    Username        string `json:"username"`
    Password        string `json:"password"`
    ConfirmPassword string `json:"confirmpassword"`
    Firstname       string `json:"firstname"`
    Lastname        string `json:"lastname"`
    Day             int    `json:"day"`
    Month           int    `json:"month"`
    Year            int    `json:"year"`
}
```

And i made this seeder:

```
var users = []User{
    {Username: "xGiovanni", Password: "nike4545", ConfirmPassword: "nike4545", Firstname: "Giovanni", Lastname: "Mosquera", Day: 27, Month: 07, Year: 2001},
    {Username: "Juseros9", Password: "contraseña", ConfirmPassword: "contraseña", Firstname: "Sebastián", Lastname: "Rodriguez", Day: 16, Month: 11, Year: 2002},
}
```

And my question is, ¿How can i add a new element with the same JSON format to the users var?
For example... add this:

```
{Username: username, Password: password, ConfirmPassword: confirm_password, Firstname: firstname, Lastname: lastname, Day: strconv.Atoi(day), Month: strconv.Atoi(month), Year: strconv.Atoi(year)}
```

Comment: You can do `users = append(users, User{...})`. See the docs on [`append`](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#append).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`append()` takes a slice of type `[]T`, and then a variable number of values of the type of the slice member T.

The solution to this is to use the `slice...`.

```
newUser := []User{
    {Username: "Juseros10", Password: "contraseña", ConfirmPassword: "contraseña", Firstname: "Sebastián", Lastname: "Rodriguez", Day: 16, Month: 11, Year: 2003},
}

users = append(users, newUser...)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the `append()` method to add new element into your users slice,here is a simple program for the same logic:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type User struct {
    Username        string `json:"username"`
    Password        string `json:"password"`
    ConfirmPassword string `json:"confirmpassword"`
    Firstname       string `json:"firstname"`
    Lastname        string `json:"lastname"`
    Day             int    `json:"day"`
    Month           int    `json:"month"`
    Year            int    `json:"year"`
}

func main() {

    var users = []User{
        {Username: "xGiovanni", Password: "nike4545", ConfirmPassword: "nike4545", Firstname: "Giovanni", Lastname: "Mosquera", Day: 27, Month: 07, Year: 2001},
        {Username: "Juseros9", Password: "contraseña", ConfirmPassword: "contraseña", Firstname: "Sebastián", Lastname: "Rodriguez", Day: 16, Month: 11, Year: 2002},
    }

    users = append(users, User{Username: "Luduvico", Password: "Einuadi", ConfirmPassword: "Einuadi", Firstname: "Ludovico", Lastname: "Einudi", Day: 25, Month: 07, Year: 1971})
    fmt.Println(users)
}
```

Output:

```
[{xGiovanni nike4545 nike4545 Giovanni Mosquera 27 7 2001} {Juseros9 contraseña contraseña Sebastián Rodriguez 16 11 2002} {Luduvico Einuadi Einuadi Ludovico Einudi 25 7 1971}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have declared a variable `a` to append data into it. You can add more variables also to append.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type User struct {
    Title, Body string
}

func main() {
    a := User{Title: "New title", Body: "New Body"}

    var new []User
    new = append(new, a)

    fmt.Println(new[0])
}
```